# What is the good practice to manage i18n with an API?

Tags: c#, .net, internationalization

I've created a small helpers framework and I want it to be multi-languages. So I used the `.resx` files for translation.

But, I'm afraid the satellites dll's will be a real mess when my framework is used into an application that has its own `.resx`...

So I'd like to know the best practices to avoid what seems to be a *resource hell*

Comment: Basically, what you are looking for are Lang(uage)Pack(age)s? So that resource dlls will be separated from code dlls? It is do-able but requires a bit of effort and you would need to override standard Assembly loading mechanism (so that you can "find" your resource files).

Comment: I just want to know if: 1- it is a good practice to used the Microsoft .rex technique and 2- what is the good practices for such a case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to follow Microsoft guidelines. Therefore *.resx files, or more precisely Satellite Assemblies is exactly what you should be using.

The problem with this approach, however is how you handle dependencies. From what I understand, you don't want to pollute the disk with additional libraries. So, you would like your clients to install just the needed files and nothing else.

The good news is, you can do that and you can still use Satellite Assemblies. All you have to do, is to pack the assembly into your DLL and override Assembly Resolution event, so that it will use internal file rather than searching for it on disk. However, with all the pros are also the cons. When you do that, your clients will have to install one file (rather large one), but they will be forced to choose from languages you provided. They won't be able to cut anything out, nor add additional language in the future.

I hope now you understand why Satellite Assembly approach is the best solution - it gives you the control over Localization process. There is no better way of handling this, sorry.
BTW. The DLL hell was related to the multiple versions of the same library needed by different clients. It won't happen in your case. Of course additional files means additional installer entries, but there is a reason why people created the concept of Merge Modules. I wouldn't worry so much for it, I would just provide framework as a merge module and let people customize it themselves, if they really have to do that.